# A DBpedia SPARQL query misses small number of triples when asking for large number of relations

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso, rdflib

I'm running the following SPARQL query on DBpedia (in fact I'm running a similar `CONSTRUCT` query via rdflib, see blow in the edited section):

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    { ?influencer dbo:influenced ?influencee .}
    UNION
    { ?influencee dbo:influencedBy ?influencer .}

    ?influencer rdf:type dbo:Person .
    ?influencee rdf:type dbo:Person .
}
```

The above query almost works, except that some (a small number of) triples is missing.

E.g. the following relation is missing:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Plato> --> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle>
```

Yet, we can see the above relation really should be included, e.g. by manually examining the [Aristotle entry on DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/page/Aristotle) and looking at the `dbo:influencedBy` section.

What's wore, is that if I augment the above code with some FILTER() expressions to limit the amount of returned tuples, I *do* get this missing relation in return:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    {?influencer dbo:influenced ?influencee .}
    UNION
    {?influencee dbo:influencedBy ?influencer .}

    ?influencer rdf:type dbo:Person .
    ?influencee rdf:type dbo:Person .

    FILTER(regex(?influencer, "Plato"))
    FILTER(regex(?influencee, "Aristo"))

}
```

**Edit 2022-07-02:** I'm aware of the 10k query result limit imposed by the DBpedia backend, yet I believe this limit is not interfering here (as hinted by TallTed [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820558/19453844)). This is because, in fact, I'm using the [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html) to run the query and -- in it -- I'm using the `CONSTRUCT` rather than the `SELECT` clause:

```py
>>> import rdflib
>>> g = rdflib.Graph()
>>> query = """
... PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
... PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
... PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
... PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
... PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
... PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
...
... CONSTRUCT {
...     ?influencer dbo:influenced ?influencee .
... }
... WHERE {
...     SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql/query> {
...             {?influencer (dbo:influenced|dbo:influences) ?influencee .}
...             UNION
...             {?influencee dbo:influencedBy ?influencer .}
...
...             ?influencer rdf:type dbo:Person .
...             ?influencee rdf:type dbo:Person .
...     }
... }"""
>>> qres = g.query(query)
>>> len(qres)
9464
```

And this query returns less than 10k...

**EDIT: 2022-07-02, part2:**
Interestingly, running the above code with the following selector:

```
SELECT ?influencer ?influencee
```

instead of the `CONSTRUCT`, returns indeed 10000 results, suggesting that I'm bouncing from the limit.

So the question really is about why my `CONSTRUCT` clause returns much less results than the `SELECT` clause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of the `COUNT(*)` on your initial query shows that there are [19,527](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+count%28*%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%7B+%3Finfluencer+dbo%3Ainfluenced+%3Finfluencee+.%7D%0D%0A++++UNION%0D%0A++++%7B+%3Finfluencee+dbo%3AinfluencedBy+%3Finfluencer+.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%3Finfluencer+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson+.%0D%0A++++%3Finfluencee+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3APerson+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on) solutions.

It is not surprising that you don't get them all when you run your query, as there's a [10,000 solution limit on that public instance](https://www.dbpedia.org/resources/sparql/#ratesandlimits) -- and it's not "a small number of" triples that's missing!

To get all solutions, you'll need to add a few clauses -- i.e., `ORDER BY ?influencer ?influencee` , `LIMIT 10000`, and `OFFSET 0` -- and then run the query to [get the first 10,000 solutions](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Finfluencer%20dbo%3Ainfluenced%20%3Finfluencee%20.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Finfluencee%20dbo%3AinfluencedBy%20%3Finfluencer%20.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Finfluencer%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Finfluencee%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Finfluencer%20%3Finfluencee%0D%0ALIMIT%2010000%0D%0AOFFSET%200&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).  Then, change the `OFFSET` clause to `OFFSET 10000` and run the query again, to [get the remaining 9,527](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Finfluencer%20dbo%3Ainfluenced%20%3Finfluencee%20.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Finfluencee%20dbo%3AinfluencedBy%20%3Finfluencer%20.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Finfluencer%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Finfluencee%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3APerson%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Finfluencer%20%3Finfluencee%0D%0ALIMIT%2010000%0D%0AOFFSET%2010000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on).

Of course, you'll probably also want to add a `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT`, as there's probably no point in repeated statements of influence.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I believe, however, the 10k limit might not be the (direct?) cause. I have edited my post above to provide more information.